# There exists a positive definite $Av=w$ if and only if $v$ and $w$ are not orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

> Let $v,w \in \mathbb R^n$ be two vectors with $v^Tw \neq 0$. Prove that there exists a positive-definite matrix $A$ such that $Av=w$.

The converse is trivial, but how do I construct a positive-definite matrix? (Can I complete to a basis in a careful way? Construct an inner product?)

Comment: does positive definite also mean symmetric?

Comment: anyway, do the 2 by 2 matrix case first,   find out why (1,0)  cannot be mapped to (0,1)  with an acceptable matrix $A$

Comment: Yes, it is symmetric. And it is the other direction that I am asking about...

Comment: so:  2 by 2, why can (1,0) (as a column vector) be mapped to $(u,v)  $ when $u \neq 0 ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not always possible. Take $v=e_1$ and $w=-e_1$. Suppose by contradiction that there exists $A$ positive- definite matrix such that

$Av=w$

So that $Ae_1=-e_1$

Then $A$ has $-1$ as eigenvalue, that contradicts $A$ to be positive definite.

Comment: Thank you. I think the correct condition is $v \cdot w > 0$.